# Why using char* arr[1] in C?

Tags: c

I came across the following code. Why `*child[1]` is used instead of `*child`?

```
struct _zend_ast {
    zend_ast_kind kind; /* Type of the node (ZEND_AST_* enum constant) */
    zend_ast_attr attr; /* Additional attribute, use depending on node type */
    uint32_t lineno;    /* Line number */
    zend_ast *child[1]; /* Array of children (using struct hack) */
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an example of the *`struct` hack*, where you can define a variable-length array member without actually using a variable-length array<sup>1</sup>.

This is probably best shown with an example.  Assume the `struct` type

```
struct foo {
  int x;
  int arr[1];
};
```

If I allocate a struct instance like so:

```
struct foo f;
```

I get enough space for `x` and a 1-element array of `int`:

```
     +---+
  x: |   |
     +---+
arr: |   | arr[0]
     +---+
```

Not terribly useful.

However, if I allocate space for the struct like this:

```
struct foo *p = malloc( sizeof *p + (4 * sizeof( int ));
```

I get something like this:

```
     +---+
  x: |   |
     +---+
arr: |   | arr[0]
     +---+
     |   | arr[1]
     +---+ 
     |   | arr[2]
     +---+
     |   | arr[3]
     +---+ 
     |   | arr[4]
     +---+
```

I've allocated enough space for all the members of the struct, plus space for an additional 4 integers.  This extra space follows `arr`, meaning I've effectively created `p->arr` as a *5*-element array of `int`.  It's as though I had defined the struct as

```
struct foo {
  int x;
  int arr[5];
};
```

This is distinct from a technique like

```
struct bar {
  int x;
  int *arr;
};

struct bar *p = malloc( sizeof *p );
if ( p )
{
  p->arr = malloc( sizeof *p->arr * 5 );
}
```

which gives me something like this:

```
     +---+
  x: |   |
     +---+
arr: |   | ---------+ 
     +---+          |
      ...           |
     +---+          |
     |   | arr[0] <-+
     +---+
     |   | arr[1]
     +---+
     |   | arr[2]
     +---+
     |   | arr[3]
     +---+ 
     |   | arr[4]
     +---+
```

The memory for `arr` is not part of the `struct` instance itself; each instance of `struct bar` is the same size.

---

1. Which is handy, since VLAs may not be members of `struct` types.

Answer (score 0):

Because this denotes an "array of pointers to zend_ast" instead of a "pointer to (an array) of zend_ast". Another, IMHO more readable way to write something with the same effect (though semantically not *exactly* the same) would be `zend_ast **child`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the author of the structure is going to use the array of undefined size. That is the structure can have a variable size depending on how many elements the last data member of the structure, the array, will have.

The last data member also could be declared as a flexible array.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the author wants to be able to use that member as array I.e. pass to functions expecting arrays, pass by address instead of value...

Answer (score 0):

The author apparently intends for the last element to be a variably-sized array of 'pointers-to-_zend_ast'. In a scheme such as this it's common to use a NULL value in the last pointer in the array as the 'end-of-array' marker. The other alternative would be to define `child` as `zend_ast **` which would then point to an entirely separate block of memory. This latter arrangement is a bit more complex and error-prone as both blocks of memory (the `struct _zend_ast` block and the `child` block) have to be released when freeing memory.

Best of luck.